# Python itertools combinations iteration control

Tags: python, iteration, combinations, python-itertools

I am using itertools to generate combinations, but I would like to control the output and be able to ask for the next entry:

```
from itertools import permutations

def getPass():
    chars = '4$5%6^7&'
    passd = ''
    for comb in permutations(chars):
       passd = ''.join(comb)     
    return passd

while(True):
    print getPass()
```

But am unable to find any relevant documentation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/2286508):

```
from itertools import permutations

def getPass():
    chars = '4$5%6^7&'
    for comb in permutations(chars):
       yield ''.join(comb)     

for i in getPass():
    print(i)
    input('\ncontinue?')
```

or even a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
from itertools import permutations

def getPass():
    return (''.join(p) for p in permutations('4$5%6^7&'))

for i in getPass():
    print(i)
    input('\ncontinue?')
```

Output:

```
4$5%6^7&

continue?
4$5%6^&7

continue?
4$5%67^&

continue?
4$5%67&^

continue?
4$5%6&^7

continue?
...
```